# Select div with up/down arrows

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have text input, and when I focusing on it - first  '.option'  of  '#number_list'  become  '.selected'.  I want to create a feature - when Up or Down key on keybord pressed than next or prev element of 'number_list' granding 'selected' class and current element loosing this class.

```
<input type="text" name="number" id="number" maxlength="30" />

<div id="number_list">
  <div class='option selected'>aaa</div>
  <div class='option'>bbb</div>
  <div class='option'>ccc</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YNyEr/

I was trying to create array of '.option' elements and get current element by index, but I don't find any way to do this. So how can it be done? Also I'm using jQuery 1.5.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this quick-and-dirty implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/YNyEr/2/

```
var $input = $('#some_number'),
    current_index = $('.selected').index(),
    $number_list = $('#number_list'),
    $options = $number_list.find('.option'),
    items_total = $options.length;

$input.val(current_index);

$input.bind('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        if (current_index + 1 < items_total) {
            current_index++;
            change_selection();
        }
    } else if (e.keyCode == 38) {
        if (current_index > 0) {
            current_index--;
            change_selection();
        }
    }
});

function change_selection()
{
    $options.removeClass('selected');
    $options.eq(current_index).addClass('selected');
    $input.val(current_index);
}​
```

Comment: I've found that it's not working in Opera, and I don't know why, can you help with it?

Comment: It's working in Opera with "keypress" event, but not working with "keyup", also in Chrome it work's conversely than in Opera. Is thare some multibrowser way out?

Answer (score -1):

I think you should have a look at the javascript events onkeyup and onkeydown.
If you play with the selection by id it should be quite easy,

For instance

```
<div onkeydown='document.getElementById("nextid").className += "selected";this.className -= "selected";' class='option'>bbb</div>
```

Comment: I mast stay focused on input when pressing up/down. And I don't actualy understand how can I do what you write in my situation. I also was using $('#number').keydown(function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 40) {...});
            }
        });

Comment: but I dont know how to change selected item and if its end of list dont changing anything

Comment: True, that was just a way to see the problem. Got to admit your answer helps way more :).